# How to click automatically in a button when user coming to page

Tags: reactjs, button, buttonclick

```
import React from "react";

checkClick = () => {
  console.log("clicked");
};

class Test extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button id="button" onClick={this.checkClick}>
          click
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Test;
```

How to click automatically on a button when user coming to page?

Here I want to click automatically above button.

I tried with:

`document.getElementById("button").click()`

which does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I do not recommend you to create functions outside of React component class. In your case, you are not able to use it like `this.checkClick` because the `checkClick` function is declared outside of your React component.

The second thing, working with real DOM inside of React is basically, let's say, antipattern. React provides virtual DOM and works with it, so, I recommend you to learn about [React ref API](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

For your case, you can use the lifecycle `componentDidMount()` method. It is being called (AUTOMATICALLY, for sure) when the component has finished its first render, so, all refs are already available here and all children elements are beind mounted and present in DOM.

```
import React from "react"

export default class Test extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    document.getElementById("button").click()
  }

  checkClick() {
    console.log("clicked!")
  }

  render() {
     return (
       <div>
         <button id="button" onClick={this.checkClick}>click</button>  
       </div>
     )
  }
}
```

or, using refs

```
import React from "react"

export default class Test extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.button.click()
  }

  checkClick() {
    console.log("clicked!")
  }

  render() {
     return (
       <div>
         <button ref={button => this.button = button} onClick={this.checkClick}>click</button>  
       </div>
     )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use a ref which gives you an instance of the dom element, where you can call the `click()` method.

If you aren't familiar with refs, you can read all about them here: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'


class Test extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.button = React.createRef()
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.button.current.click()
  }

  checkClick() {
    console.log('clicked')
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button ref={this.button} onClick={this.checkClick}>Click me!</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


export default Test
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me when input type is file. i can make it work by clicking on a parent component to trigger rendering of the child component, but then the input dissappears from the DOM and none of the synthetic events of React work since the whole form is gone

Answer (score 1):

Use `componentDidMount` for that,

```
import React from 'react';


class Test extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount(){
       this.checkClick();
    }
     checkClick () {
         console.log("clicked");
     }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button id="button" onClick={this.checkClick}>click</button> 
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default Test;
```

Comment: No. Button is there and it should click button automaticall. not using componentdidmount

Comment: @soubhagya well, the lifecycle `componentDidMount` is being called automatially. So, if you fire `somebutton.click()` inside of it, it means, that this button will be clicked automatically

Comment: @LevitatorImbalance Exactly, the ultimate motive is to fire the onClick function and the above code will work

Comment: it won't when input type is file...